# AngularJs - Bootstrap - close modal window

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using angular 1.2 and angular-bootstrap modal directive. I have a Controller1 that opens a modal window. There I load external application in iframe. When user finishes working with external application, that application calls returnUrl, parameter I provide before making call. External application adds some parameters to my returnUrl, so I can read what happened there (not important at this point).

```
myApp.controller('Controller1', [ '$scope', '$rootScope', '$modal', function($scope, $rootScope, $modal){
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl : 'modalContent.html',
        controller : 'Controller2',
        backdrop : 'static'
    });
    modalInstance.result.then(function(){
        //
    }, function(){
        $rootScope.loadingScreen.hide();
    });
} ]);

myApp.controller('Controller2', [ '$scope', '$modalInstance', '$rootScope', function($scope, $modalInstance, $rootScope){
    // returning from modal window
    $rootScope.$on('event:return-from-external', function(){
    //never gets here?
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    });
    $scope.cancel = function(){
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
} ]);
```

To read what happened in external application I made a router that handles a return from external application:

```
myApp.config([ '$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when('/returnFromModalWindow/:id', {
        templateUrl : 'returnFromModalWindow/returnFromModalWindow-list.tpl.html', //just to show loader
        controller : 'ReturnFromModalWindowController'
    });
} ]);
```

This rooter have controller ReturnFromModalWindowController that do some logic and than should close modal window and return to my application.

```
myApp.controller('ReturnFromModalWindowController', [ '$scope', '$routeParams', '$rootScope', function($scope, $routeParams, $rootScope){
    //read parameters
    //do some logic
    //emit to close modal window
    $rootScope.$emit('event:return-from-external');
} ]);
```

Problem is that I never catch emitted 'event:return-from-external' in Controller2.
How to close a modal window in this situation? $rootScope.$on is not working or maybe there is a better way to do this?

Comment: Use `$broadcast`. You will want to use `$broadcast` when there isn't no parent-child connection between scopes, and this will "broadcast" the event to all the child scopes.

Comment: Shouldn't `ReturnFromModalWindowController` just `$scope.$emit` (instead of `$rootScope.$broadcast` or `$rootScope.$emit`)? The event should bubble up to `$rootScope`.

Comment: If you change, `$rootScope.$emit('event:return-from-external');` to use `$rootScope.$broadcast` and also change in your Controller2 `$rootScope.$on('event:return-from-external'` to use $scope rather than $rootScope. And yes you are correct that it should bubble up to the `$rootScope`. But then explain this you are using currently in your controller2 `$rootScope.$emit('event..)` and you want it to register the `$on` event.

Comment: According to the angular documentation it states `$emit`: Dispatches an event name upwards through the scope hierarchy notifying the registered $rootScope.Scope listeners. You are trying to dispatch an event up the scope hierarchy using $rootScope.$emit. If you want to use `$emit` in your `ReturnFromModalWindowController` change this to `$scope.$emit` and leave your controller2 as it is

Comment: None of these combination worked. I tried all combinations, but never catches a emitted event. It seems that problem is that I'm using a iframe?! Still searching for solution.